# Stuck when using WHERE ... IN in my DQL

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, where-in

I'm trying to use a `WHERE ... IN ()` clause in my DQL, but somehow get stuck. I expect a result of three articles (`WHERE a.id IN (1,2,20)`), but only get one article (with `id=1`) as result. The articles definitely exist in that specific team I set as another parameter.

The SQL (I use for `$q = $em->createQuery($sql)`) looks like this:

```
SELECT a
FROM AcmeBundle:Article a
WHERE a.team = :team
AND a.id IN (:listOfArticleIds)
ORDER BY a.updated DESC
```

The DQL (`$q->getSql()`) it creates is this:

```
SELECT a0_.id AS id0, a0_.title AS title1, a0_.description AS description2, a0_.status AS status3, a0_.created AS created4, a0_.updated AS updated5, a0_.contributor_id AS contributor_id6, a0_.company_id AS company_id7
FROM Article a0_
WHERE a0_.team_id = ? AND a0_.id IN (?)
ORDER BY a0_.updated DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

The parameters (`$q->getParameters()`) look like this

```
object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)#647 (1) {
  ["_elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter)#646 (3) {
      ["name":"Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter":private]=>
      string(4) "team"
      ["value":"Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter":private]=>
      int(1)
      ["type":"Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter":private]=>
      string(7) "integer"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter)#520 (3) {
      ["name":"Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter":private]=>
      string(13) "listOfArticleIds"
      ["value":"Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter":private]=>
      string(6) "1,2,20"
      ["type":"Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parameter":private]=>
      int(2)
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone has an idea what might be wrong here? I'm curious about the type of the `listOfArticleIds` parameter, that is `int(2)`, but I would expect it to be a `string`. I already manually set it to `string` (`$q->setParameter('listOfArticleIds', $listOfArticleIds, 'string')`) but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listOfArticleIds` should be an array, like:

```
$q->setParameter('listOfArticleIds', array(1, 2, 20))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I imploded the parameters before, so I can simply omit the implosion.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the parameter as array and not as string, doctrine will implode it automatically.

I remember it works only with array of integer but i'm not sure, I use querybuilder:).